# Why two select query can't execute in one php code?

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner and first time works with database i have problem for executing two query.Please show me some solution for it.

My code is as follow:-

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
      {

     // echo "value is .".$a; 

    echo $_POST["gr_num"];
    echo $_POST["school_code"];


    $sqlstr="select studentname from gr_master where grid='".$_POST["gr_num"]."' and schoolcode='".$_POST["school_code"]."'";
    $sqlstr1="select schoolname from school_master where schoolcode='".$_POST["school_code"]."'";


    $result=mysql_query($sqlstr);
    $result1=mysql_query($sqlstr1);

    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);

    echo $row["studentname"];
    $studentname_var=$row['studentname'].'"';
    echo $studentname_var;
}
```

Here this `$row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);` generates error so how to execute two query here without any function like mysqli_multi_query().

Comment: as bad as this is , in theory it should work, whats the error message?

Comment: Debug your code and mention the error you're getting >>> $result=mysql_query($sqlstr) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @Dagon Undefined variable: row1

Comment: i would be expecting to see a while loop

Comment: what values are being posted in `gr_num` and `school_code`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug your code using the basic **die()** and **print_r()** functions.

See where exactly your query is stuck:

```
 $result = mysql_query($sqlstr) or die("Query 1 Error: ".mysql_error());
 $row    = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 $result1 = mysql_query($sqlstr1) or die("Query 2 Error: ".mysql_error());
 $row1    = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

 echo "<pre">;
 print_r($row);
 print_r($row1);
```

Let me know what's being printed.

Comment: a suggestion to stop using the dangerous and depreciated mysql* would be good

Comment: @Dagon 'deprecated' !!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use PDO. mysql is removed from PHP 7.

But still you want to use it, it's up to you!

> And you are saying that it's an error. It's not an error. It's showing you a notice. Queries are running fine!

You can stop notices from your php.ini file or php code:

> ini_set('display_errors',0);
>   error_reporting(E_ALL);